# How to use nested parallel in place of loops

Tags: linux, while-loop, parallel-processing, bioinformatics, gnu

I am trying to parallelize this loop where I already have used one parallel to process paired set of output into .gz files. Is there a way to use another parallel in this code?

```
srr_count=0; 
while [ ${srr_count} -lt 10 ]; do 
  for SRR in $(cat SRR_10ids.list); do 
    if ! [ -f ${SRR}_1.fastq.gz ]; then 
      fasterq-dump ${SRR} && parallel -j2 'gzip {}' ::: *.fastq;
    else 
      ((srr_count+=1)); 
    fi; 
  done;
done
```

This is to download data from NCBI SRA (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra). Often, I get connection error while downloading these data, so I had to use if/else fault check in this code. So, in place of passing only one ID i.e, `${SRR}` for `fasterq-dump` command to execute, I want to pass multiple IDs. Is there a way to change this code to do so?

Comment: This looks like a job for make. What should the result be of that script?

Comment: @KamilCuk The result should produce 10*2 `.fastq.gz` files. I just wanted to speed up the whole process.